# Eiffel: How do I handle timezones?

Tags: timezone, eiffel

I didn't find any notion of **timezone** DATE_TIME class and TIME class. Am I wrong?

How do I handle **timezones** with Eiffel library?

Is there a way to specify it from the `{DATE_TIME}.formated_out ("YYYY-MM-DD [0]hh:[0]mi:[0]ss")`

Is there a **setter** for timezone?

I already got this problem with the **logger** which is logging with UTC...

The only **workaround** I found was `l.hour_add (-3)` before the formated_out which is really dirty

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, class `DATE_TIME` does not contain any information about the time zone the date time is supposed to be in.

If your logger need UTC times, you might want to use:

```
create l_date_time.make_now_utc
```

instead of:

```
create l_date_time.make_now
```

Note that the Gobo Eiffel libaries have some rudimentary support for timezones, but it's not any better than doing `l_date_time.hour_add (-3)` because the date/time need to be converted from one timezone to another before being printed.

```
local
    l_date_time: DT_DATE_TIME
    l_time_zone: DT_FIXED_OFFSET_TIME_ZONE
    l_date_time_formatter: ST_XSD_DATE_TIME_FORMAT
    s: STRING
do
    create l_date_time_formatter
    create l_time_zone.make_hours_minutes (-3, 0)
    l_date_time := {DT_SHARED_SYSTEM_CLOCK}.system_clock.date_time_now
    s := l_date_time_formatter.date_time_to_string (l_time_zone.date_time_to_utc (l_date_time))
```

There is also a class `DT_FIXED_OFFSET_ZONED_DATE_TIME`, but I'm afraid it will not make the code above less verbose because you still need to provide to it the date time and its associated timezone.

You might also want to have a look at this other Eiffel library: [ISO8601 date/time library](https://github.com/eiffelhub/iso8601)